# cybersource rejects any value currency

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I'm trying to integrate cybersource payment proccessor to my web app and of course I need to test the transaction.

My proceed checkout form:

```
   <form  method="post" action="https://orderpagetest.ic3.com/hop/ProcessOrder.do">
       <input type="text" name="billTo_city" value="Mountain View"><br>
       <input type="text" name="billTo_country" value="us"><br>
       <input type="text" name="billTo_firstName" value="John"><br>
       <input type="text" name="billTo_lastName" value="Doe"><br>
       <input type="text" name="billTo_postalCode" value="94043"><br>
       <input type="text" name="billTo_state" value="CA"><br>
       <input type="text" name="billingStreetAddress1" value="1295 Charleston Rd."><br>
       <input type="text" name="creditCardNumber" value="4111111111111111"><br>
       <input type="text" name="creditCardType" value="001"><br>
       <input type="text" name="card_expirationMonth" value="07"><br>
       <input type="text" name="card_expirationYear" value="2013"><br>
       <input type="text" name="currency" value="USD"><br>
       <input type="text" name="merchantID" value="alljobs"><br>
       <input type="text" name="amount" value="1"><br>
       <input type="text" name="cardVerificationNumber" value="1234"><br>
       <input type="text" name="orderPage_environment" value="test"><br>
       <input type="text" name="" value="Authorization"><br>
       <input type="text" name="paymentType" value="card"><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy Now">
    </form>
```

I filled out all the required fields and sending form to debug page cybersource by 'silent order post method'

All field success validation, but **currency** field validation error. I can not understand why and what I did wrong? In my test business cabinet in virtual terminal->settings currency set up as United States dollar

Answer (score 0):

3 things I would try:

1. most of the currencies require a price specified with two decimal places
2. submit the form to:
   `https://orderpagetest.ic3.com/hop/orderform.jsp`
   (according to: http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/HOP_UG/Hosted_Order_Page_UG.pdf)
3. the following two fields are mandatory for "HOP", add them to the request:

   orderPage_signaturePublic
   orderPage_timestamp

Check out the POST examples on page 105 in the link above!

Comment: where I can generate a HOP file? i think it's a problem, because according the guide in 51 page: 
Tools & Settings >  Hosted Order Page > Security (place for generating hop file)
But Tools and Setting section does not have anything like Hosted Order Page!(such as all another sections) http://d.pr/i/kxPg. please help me how to generate hop file!

Comment: @jehkinen do you found any soultion ? i am having same problem that i am not getting from where i can generate HOP File

Comment: Did it help to anyone? I still have the same issue.